# How to lock versions of nested dependencies for package managers?

Tags: version-control, version, dependency-management, package-managers

Today I experienced how the good practice of not storing dependencies in Git can bite me hard.

I have bower.json file and I have set fixed version numbers to avoid unexpected updates. For example,

`"angular-google-maps": "angular-ui/angular-google-maps#2.2.1"`

But I forgot that libraries might have nested dependencies and I have no control over these.

So, today my build broke because lodash in angular-google-maps was specified as `"lodash": ">=3.8.0"` . 
Initially I had version 3.10.1 for a few months or so. But after cloning a clean copy and running my build scripts, lodash version 4.2.1 was installed. In the new versions folder structure has been changed, therefore my build was broken.

This time the fix was easy - just adjust my paths. But there might be worse situations. For example, some library might have an old bug and I might have custom code which works around the bug. Then the library gets updated with a bugfix, bower fetches the new library, and my workaround is in best case redundant, or in worst case causes some serious damage.

I'm not sure, how to avoid this in the future. I really don't want to iterate through all recursive dependencies and add them to my bower.json, package.json etc. as fixed version numbers. That's insane. There should be some automated tool. Ok, composer has .lock, but I'm not sure if it locks also the nested dependencies.

Another issue is build consistency. Let's say, we have a master branch with a version tag 1.2.3. When I checkout this tag and collect all the dependencies, I expect to always get the same resulting code, but it is not so. This means that I cannot deliver the same exact code to production. I'll have to cache my builds somewhere to always be sure that the same exact code is available.

**How do other developers deal with this? Is there any alternative to committing all dependencies into Git?**